# which version SQL server can Install Windows 10?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have Os Windows 10. I am trying to install SQL Server 2012. After installing I try to connect to the server, the connection to the server returns the following error message:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2)
>
> For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=2&LinkId=20476

In Services I cannot see MS SQL Server.

Comment: Did you installed the database engine feature, it seems not . What version you were trying to install ?

Comment: sql server 2012  sir

Comment: I am sorry I should have asked edition. Which edition are you trying to install, is this express edition. Can you paste here the name of downloaded file you are running to install SQL Server. Just so that you know SQL Server 2012 with Sp2 is supported on windows 10.

Comment: SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU   sir  actually installed finished but i cant able  to login server

Comment: You have only installed SQL Server Management Studio, which is the GUI, not SQL Server itself.

Comment: sorry sir i am not clear please explain little bit more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just installed `SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU` this is SQL Server management studio. This is a tool used to connect to SQL server database engine. Since you have not installed SQL Server database engine you cannot connect.

- You have to browse [This Link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43351)
- Click on download
- Then you would get something like below

[image]

- Downlaod the files marked in rectangle. Assuming you have 64 bit windows you would have to download first one `SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe`. If you have 32 bit download the second one marked in rectangle.
- After you have finished downloading install it and then use SSMS to connect.
- If you are unable to connect after installing database engine, its quite possible that SQL server has not started. Go to `Services.msc` look for SQl Server service and if it is stopped start it and then try connecting.

Comment: sir now uninstall  all. now Going  install SQL EXPR_X64_ENU.exe  its only or need to install both two ?

Comment: Don't uninstall anything. Just download and install what is mentioned in answer. You just need to install `SQL EXPR_X64_ENU` assuming you have 64 bit windows. You dont have to install both

Comment: thank you sir i have OS Windows 10 64 bit Using I have Follow  your Mention method Sir

Comment: HI, Guys please help me to resolve the error while installing, The error message says "The feature you are trying to use is on a network resource that in unavailable. Click ok to try again, or enter an alternate path to a folder containing the installation package 'sqlncli.msi' in the box below"