# Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 Service Pack 2 (SP2) Express

Tags: sql-server-2012

[which version SQL server can Install Windows 10?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/139330/which-version-sql-server-can-install-windows-10)

Is  SQLManagementStudio_x86_ENU.exe  free ?

Comment: What are you trying to install, an actual sql instance, or just the management studio?

Comment: recommend a newer free version of the sql server express (free) with SSMS, please

Comment: Thanks Yannick for answer.
I've would both.

So far I have used sql server 2005 (no express version)

Comment: I've would both.
So far I have used sql server 2005 (no express version)
Can you recommend me a newer free version of the sql server express (free) with SSMS, please ?

Comment: Check my answer below, it should have everything you need.

Answer (score 1):

As you said in comments you'd like a SQL Server + a SSMS.
I would suggest not using a SQL2012, but going for a more recent version.

Using this [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads) link you can download the SQL Server itself.
The 2 free versions are express and Developer. More information about the differences between versions can be found here : [SQL Editions](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-2017-editions) and [SQL Pricing](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-2017-pricing)

- Developer you should use if you're just trying to develop some things at home, NOT COMMERCIALLY. It has all the features enterprise has.
- Express will give you a basic sql server with some limitations.

Afterwards you can get SSMS using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15) link.
SSMS is free, and its just used to work on your SQL Server

Comment: Hi Yannick  and thanks for answer.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads

Will I be wrong if I download:
Express  or  if download Developer ?

Are both is free, non commercial?

What you can me recomended, what is better (must be free) ?

Second step:
download SSMI from:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Developer should be use for personal/dev use, if you want to do anything for your business you have to take the express version. It just depends what you want to use it for.

Comment: @YannickLiekens Developer edition can be used for business purposes, just not in *production* environments. Only Express can be used for free for production purposes.

Answer (score 0):

second part first - yes SSMS the management studio is indeed free - and latest version should be 18.4.

after the hassle to find a suitable SQL-Server for our environment, I'd say that all the newer ones do work with windows 10 - especially from 2014 onward (the 2014 is the last one willing to be installed on windows 7)

Why do you mention the x86 variant? except some computers from fresh after the stone age all released and build in the last 10 years should be able to run the 64bit version .. which is the preferred release for MSSQL server anyway

Comment: eagle275 wrote:
Why do you mention the x86 variant?
yes, i know, you are right.
I wrote it incorrectly